# Error Building Grails Application

Tags: grails

When I am building my application, I am getting the following error please help.

```
| Error Compilation error: startup failed:
General error during class generation: Method code too large!
java.lang.RuntimeException: Method code too large!
```

No error while running application,error on making war.

- > | Compiling 194 source files. | Compiling 194 source files.. |
  >   Compiling 194 source files... | Compiling 194 source files.... |
  >   Compiling 194 source files..... | Compiling 244 GSP files for package 
  >   [app] | Compiling 244 GSP files for package [app]. | Error
  >   Compilation error: startup failed: General error during class
  >   generation: Method code too large! java.lang.RuntimeException: Method 
  >   code too large! at groovyjarjarasm.asm.MethodWriter.a(Unknown Source) 
  >   at groovyjarjarasm.asm.ClassWriter.toByteArray(Unknown Source) at
  >   org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit$14.call(CompilationUnit.java:788)
  >   at
  >   org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.applyToPrimaryClassNodes(CompilationUnit.java:1027)
  >   at
  >   org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.doPhaseOperation(CompilationUnit.java:564)
  >   at
  >   org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.processPhaseOperations(CompilationUnit.java:542)
  >   at
  >   org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.compile(CompilationUnit.java:519)
  >   at
  >   org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.compile(CompilationUnit.java:498)
  >   at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit$compile.call(Unknown
  >   Source) at
  >   org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.pages.GroovyPageCompiler$_compileGSP_closure1.doCall(GroovyPageCompiler.groovy:144)
  >   at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor190.invoke(Unknown Source) at
  >   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
  >   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597) at
  >   org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
  >   at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233) at
  >   groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1082) at
  >   groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1106) 
  >   at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:906) at
  >   groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:412) at
  >   groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:425) at
  >   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.IOGroovyMethods.withStream(IOGroovyMethods.java:1160)
  >   at
  >   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ResourceGroovyMethods.withInputStream(ResourceGroovyMethods.java:1523)
  >   at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.dgm$841.invoke(Unknown Source) at
  >   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaMethodSite$PojoMetaMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PojoMetaMethodSite.java:271)
  >   at
  >   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaMethodSite.call(PojoMetaMethodSite.java:53)
  >   at
  >   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
  >   at
  >   org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.pages.GroovyPageCompiler.compileGSP(GroovyPageCompiler.groovy:121)
  >   at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor187.invoke(Unknown Source) at
  >   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
  >   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597) at
  >   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:272)
  >   at
  >   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:52)
  >   at
  >   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:153)
  >   at
  >   org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.pages.GroovyPageCompiler.compile(GroovyPageCompiler.groovy:61)
  >   at
  >   org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.pages.GroovyPageCompiler$compile.call(Unknown
  >   Source) at
  >   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
  >   at
  >   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
  >   at
  >   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:112)
  >   at
  >   org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.pages.GroovyPageCompilerTask.execute(GroovyPageCompilerTask.groovy:117)
  >   at
  >   org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
  >   at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor111.invoke(Unknown Source) at
  >   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
  >   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597) at
  >   org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
  >   at groovy.util.AntBuilder.performTask(AntBuilder.java:260) at
  >   groovy.util.AntBuilder.nodeCompleted(AntBuilder.java:220) at
  >   groovy.util.BuilderSupport.doInvokeMethod(BuilderSupport.java:147) at 
  >   groovy.util.AntBuilder.doInvokeMethod(AntBuilder.java:170) at
  >   groovy.util.BuilderSupport.invokeMethod(BuilderSupport.java:64) at
  >   org.codehaus.gant.GantBuilder.invokeMethod(GantBuilder.java:99) at
  >   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.call(PogoMetaClassSite.java:45)
  >   at
  >   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
  >   at
  >   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
  >   at
  >   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
  >   at
  >   org.codehaus.groovy.grails.compiler.GrailsProjectCompiler.compileGroovyPages(GrailsProjectCompiler.groovy:384)
  >   at
  >   org.codehaus.groovy.grails.compiler.GrailsProjectCompiler$compileGroovyPages.call(Unknown
  >   Source) at
  >   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
  >   at
  >   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
  >   at
  >   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:120)
  >   at
  >   _GrailsCompile_groovy$_run_closure5.doCall(_GrailsCompile_groovy:92) at
  >   org.codehaus.gant.GantMetaClass.processClosure(GantMetaClass.java:81) 
  >   at
  >   org.codehaus.gant.GantMetaClass.processArgument(GantMetaClass.java:95)
  >   at
  >   org.codehaus.gant.GantMetaClass.invokeMethod(GantMetaClass.java:128)
  >   at
  >   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaClassSite.java:66)
  >   at
  >   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:49)
  >   at
  >   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:133)
  >   at _GrailsWar_groovy$_run_closure2.doCall(_GrailsWar_groovy:41) at
  >   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at
  >   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
  >   at
  >   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
  >   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597) at
  >   org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
  >   at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233) at
  >   groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1082) at
  >   groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1106) 
  >   at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:906) at
  >   groovy.lang.DelegatingMetaClass.invokeMethod(DelegatingMetaClass.java:149)
  >   at
  >   org.codehaus.gant.GantMetaClass.invokeMethod(GantMetaClass.java:133)
  >   at
  >   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.call(PogoMetaClassSite.java:39)
  >   at
  >   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
  >   at
  >   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.call(PogoMetaClassSite.java:54)
  >   at
  >   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
  >   at
  >   org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16_closure18.doCall(GantBinding.groovy:185)
  >   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at
  >   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
  >   at
  >   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
  >   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597) at
  >   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSite.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:231)
  >   at
  >   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:52)
  >   at
  >   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:141)
  >   at
  >   org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16_closure18.doCall(GantBinding.groovy)
  >   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at
  >   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
  >   at
  >   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
  >   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597) at
  >   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:272)
  >   at
  >   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.call(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:64)
  >   at
  >   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:112)
  >   at
  >   org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding.withTargetEvent(GantBinding.groovy:90)
  >   at
  >   org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding.this$4$withTargetEvent(GantBinding.groovy)
  >   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at
  >   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
  >   at
  >   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
  >   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597) at
  >   org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
  >   at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233) at
  >   groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1082) at
  >   groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1106) 
  >   at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:906) at
  >   groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1027) at
  >   groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1106) 
  >   at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:906) at
  >   groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:727) at
  >   groovy.lang.GroovyObjectSupport.invokeMethod(GroovyObjectSupport.java:44)
  >   at
  >   groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethodOnGroovyObject(MetaClassImpl.java:1147)
  >   at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1041) at 
  >   groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1106) 
  >   at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:906) at
  >   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaClassSite.java:66)
  >   at
  >   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:149)
  >   at
  >   org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16.doCall(GantBinding.groovy:185)
  >   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at
  >   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
  >   at
  >   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
  >   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597) at
  >   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSite.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:231)
  >   at
  >   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:52)
  >   at
  >   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:141)
  >   at
  >   org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16.doCall(GantBinding.groovy)
  >   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at
  >   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
  >   at
  >   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
  >   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597) at
  >   org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
  >   at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233) at
  >   groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1082) at
  >   groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1106) 
  >   at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:906) at
  >   groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:412) at
  >   groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:406) at
  >   org.codehaus.gant.GantMetaClass.processClosure(GantMetaClass.java:81) 
  >   at
  >   org.codehaus.gant.GantMetaClass.processArgument(GantMetaClass.java:95)
  >   at
  >   org.codehaus.gant.GantMetaClass.invokeMethod(GantMetaClass.java:128)
  >   at
  >   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaClassSite.java:66)
  >   at
  >   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:49)
  >   at
  >   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:133)
  >   at
  >   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:145)
  >   at War$_run_closure1.doCall(War.groovy:38) at
  >   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at
  >   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
  >   at
  >   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
  >   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597) at
  >   org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
  >   at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233) at
  >   groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1082) at
  >   groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1106) 
  >   at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:906) at
  >   groovy.lang.DelegatingMetaClass.invokeMethod(DelegatingMetaClass.java:149)
  >   at
  >   org.codehaus.gant.GantMetaClass.invokeMethod(GantMetaClass.java:133)
  >   at
  >   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.call(PogoMetaClassSite.java:39)
  >   at
  >   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
  >   at
  >   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.call(PogoMetaClassSite.java:54)
  >   at
  >   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
  >   at
  >   org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16_closure18.doCall(GantBinding.groovy:185)
  >   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at
  >   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
  >   at
  >   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
  >   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597) at
  >   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSite.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:231)
  >   at
  >   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:52)
  >   at
  >   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:141)
  >   at
  >   org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16_closure18.doCall(GantBinding.groovy)
  >   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at
  >   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
  >   at
  >   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
  >   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597) at
  >   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:272)
  >   at
  >   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.call(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:64)
  >   at
  >   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:112)
  >   at
  >   org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding.withTargetEvent(GantBinding.groovy:90)
  >   at
  >   org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding.this$4$withTargetEvent(GantBinding.groovy)
  >   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at
  >   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
  >   at
  >   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
  >   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597) at
  >   org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
  >   at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233) at
  >   groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1082) at
  >   groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1106) 
  >   at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:906) at
  >   groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1027) at
  >   groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1106) 
  >   at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:906) at
  >   groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:727) at
  >   groovy.lang.GroovyObjectSupport.invokeMethod(GroovyObjectSupport.java:44)
  >   at
  >   groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethodOnGroovyObject(MetaClassImpl.java:1147)
  >   at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1041) at 
  >   groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1106) 
  >   at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:906) at
  >   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaClassSite.java:66)
  >   at
  >   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:149)
  >   at
  >   org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16.doCall(GantBinding.groovy:185)
  >   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at
  >   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
  >   at
  >   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
  >   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597) at
  >   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSite.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:231)
  >   at
  >   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:52)
  >   at
  >   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:141)
  >   at
  >   org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16.doCall(GantBinding.groovy)
  >   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at
  >   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
  >   at
  >   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
  >   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597) at
  >   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:272)
  >   at
  >   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.call(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:64)
  >   at
  >   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
  >   at
  >   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
  >   at
  >   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:112)
  >   at gant.Gant$_dispatch_closure5.doCall(Gant.groovy:381) at
  >   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at
  >   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
  >   at
  >   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
  >   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597) at
  >   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:272)
  >   at
  >   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.call(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:64)
  >   at
  >   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
  >   at
  >   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
  >   at
  >   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
  >   at gant.Gant$_dispatch_closure7.doCall(Gant.groovy:415) at
  >   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at
  >   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
  >   at
  >   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
  >   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597) at
  >   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSite.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:231)
  >   at
  >   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:52)
  >   at
  >   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:49)
  >   at
  >   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:133)
  >   at
  >   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:141)
  >   at gant.Gant$_dispatch_closure7.doCall(Gant.groovy) at
  >   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at
  >   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
  >   at
  >   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
  >   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597) at
  >   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:272)
  >   at
  >   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.call(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:64)
  >   at
  >   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
  >   at
  >   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
  >   at
  >   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:112)
  >   at gant.Gant.withBuildListeners(Gant.groovy:427) at
  >   gant.Gant.this$2$withBuildListeners(Gant.groovy) at
  >   gant.Gant$this$2$withBuildListeners.callCurrent(Unknown Source) at
  >   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:49)
  >   at
  >   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:133)
  >   at
  >   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:141)
  >   at gant.Gant.dispatch(Gant.groovy:415) at
  >   gant.Gant.this$2$dispatch(Gant.groovy) at
  >   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at
  >   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
  >   at
  >   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
  >   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597) at
  >   org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
  >   at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233) at
  >   groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1082) at
  >   groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1106) 
  >   at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:906) at
  >   groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:729) at
  >   gant.Gant.invokeMethod(Gant.groovy) at
  >   groovy.lang.GroovyObject$invokeMethod.callCurrent(Unknown Source) at
  >   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:49)
  >   at
  >   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:133)
  >   at
  >   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:145)
  >   at gant.Gant.executeTargets(Gant.groovy:591) at
  >   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at
  >   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
  >   at
  >   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
  >   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597) at
  >   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSite.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:231)
  >   at
  >   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:52)
  >   at
  >   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:49)
  >   at
  >   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:133)
  >   at
  >   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:145)
  >   at gant.Gant.executeTargets(Gant.groovy:590) at
  >   org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.GrailsScriptRunner.executeWithGantInstance(GrailsScriptRunner.java:769)
  >   at
  >   org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.GrailsScriptRunner.executeScriptFile(GrailsScriptRunner.java:567)
  >   at
  >   org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.GrailsScriptRunner.executeScriptWithCaching(GrailsScriptRunner.java:466)
  >   at
  >   org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.GrailsScriptRunner.callPluginOrGrailsScript(GrailsScriptRunner.java:410)
  >   at
  >   org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.GrailsScriptRunner.executeCommand(GrailsScriptRunner.java:374)
  >   at
  >   org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.GrailsScriptRunner.main(GrailsScriptRunner.java:232)
  >   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at
  >   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
  >   at
  >   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
  >   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597) at
  >   org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.support.GrailsStarter.rootLoader(GrailsStarter.java:234)
  >   at
  >   org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.support.GrailsStarter.main(GrailsStarter.java:262)
  >   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at
  >   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
  >   at
  >   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
  >   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597) at
  >   org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.support.GrailsStarter.rootLoader(GrailsStarter.java:234)
  >   at
  >   org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.support.GrailsStarter.main(GrailsStarter.java:262)
  >   1 error above

---

Comment: Can you please add the complete stacktrace?

Comment: micha,please look @ stackoverflow.log

Answer (score 1):

http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-10246

Please look at the jira bug reported for the same. You need to divide your method into some smaller methods.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your reply,I have nothing writtern on bootstrap,to which method i have to make changes?.

Comment: please find the method in your code... actually grails / groovy doesn't like long method. I've already faced this problem and cutting a large method into smaller makes my code compilable.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the solution to this. The Java class files are created during the compile process. Whereas the JSP/GSP class files are created during **runtime**.
  So, while compiling a JSP/GSP file, a ***class file is created having the a single method which will contain the code within the JSP/GSP page***. If the size of this method exceeds 65k then you will get this error.
  In order to avoid this, I recommend that you **break down** your JSP/GSP pages into various JSP/GSP pages and use **<@include> OR**  to include them.
By doing this, each JSP/GSP will be treated as a different method and the size will **not exceed 65k**. This helped me. Hope it does in your case as well.

Answer (score 0):

I have met this issue before. And one of problems causes this error may come from the method "`Eval`" in your source codes. You can try to use another alternative method to avoid this compilation error. I tried and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

The JVM has a limitation on the method size which cannot be greater than 65536 bytes. In order to avoid this error you can split the method into smaller methods. It is also a good practice to write small piece of code as it is easy to understand and debug the code.
Mean while you can see the post "[Method Size Limit in Java](http://chrononsystems.com/blog/method-size-limit-in-java)".